# Arrow's Impossibility Theorem Using Boolean Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, boolean-algebra, economics, social-choice-theory

I am currently working on a research project which involves using Boolean matrices for the proof of Arrow's Impossibility Theorem and various other lemmas and results related to quasi ordered sets. In short, I need to construct mathematical proofs from logical results found in various Economics books (eg: Collective Choice and Social Welfare by Amartya Sen). At present, I am referring to a book called Applied Abstract Algebra by Kim and Roush (Chapter 1 mainly) for the mathematical proofs. Can anyone give suggest any other books or research papers or online sources that I can look into to get a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

The only book in this literature that made any sense to me was Balinski and Laraki: Majority Judgement